# Qual a melhor forma de tratar Exceptions e Log em WebAPI (C#)?

Tags: c#, exceção, asp.net-web-api, log

**Cenário:** WebAPIs em .NET 4.x

**Objetivo:** Melhorar o Logging (info, error, debug, warning) e Exception Handling, por exemplo, logar as exceptions, qual frameworks de Logs utilizam? Onde costumam armazenar Logs? Achei uma ferramenta chamada [DataDog](http://datadoghq.com/) alguém já viu ?

achei esses steps aqui também:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028919/catch-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api

**Edit**

Minha pergunta foi marcada como duplicada.. porém não encontrei nada relacionado com o contexto (EXCEPTION + LOG).. apenas Log... meu foco é Exception também.

Comment: Já trabalhou com log4net? Ele trabalha com arquivos text e bancos de dados. Sua instalação e configuração não é complexa. Dá uma pesquisada nele...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que sobre o local de armazenar, eu gosto de ferramentas que armazenam em N locais, o log tem que persiste você não pode ficar referem de um meio de acesso ao mesmo. Por isso eu utilizo [serilog](https://serilog.net/) , ele persiste em diversas formar inclusive no banco e arquivos (Que são as mais utilizadas).

Não conheço o DataDog, mas no geral as ferramentas são bem parecidas, tente achar uma que te atenda e que tenha bastantes usuarios que é o caso do serilog e do log4net, assim você garante a boa manutenção em caso de problema nos mesmos. O importante é o bom tratamento no código e uma boa infra para armazenar.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo dar uma olhada no [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)  que é bem popular e é possível encontrar conteúdos interessantes em portugês (Ex: [Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/13/11/net_log41.htm)) e no [Elmah](https://elmah.github.io/) que é uma ferramenta bem completa e muito interessante.